# mysqli access denied (42000/1044) linux permissions?

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, permissions

I get the php error

> mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user
>   'sec_user01'@'localhost' to database 'secure_login'

I created the database with:

```
CREATE DATABASE `secure_login`;
I created the user with 
CREATE USER 'sec_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '**********************';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `secure_login`.* TO 'sec_user'@'localhost';
```

I connect to the db using

```
 include_once 'web_psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

the config file is included successfully.
this worked up till a few hours ago. 
The only thing I can think of that changed is that in my php script I made some folders with 755 access. Is it possible that the permissions from the files from which this script is executed are causing this error ?

I am really stumped.

edit: I tested this with an ADODB connection

```
require('../scripts/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
$ADODB_CACHE_DIR = 'adodb5cache'; 

$Host = "localhost";
$Database = "secure_login";
$Databasetype ="mysql";

// lijst users en passwd
$DbAdminUser="sec_user01";
$DbAdminUserPassword="**************";

$debug = true; //debug on
//$debug = false; //debug off
//admin connection
$dbconn = ADONewConnection($Databasetype);
$dbconn->Connect($Host, $DbAdminUser, $DbAdminUserPassword, $Database);

$query="SELECT * FROM members;";
$ammount=$dbconn->GetAll($query);
print_r($ammount);
```

and this works. Is this some kind of bug in mysqli ?
I really hope I don't have to rewrite to use ADODB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to login into phpmyadmin with those credentials. If unsuccessful then your credentials might not matching.

Comment: When I login into phpmyadmin I can login but I don't see the database.
in the table USER_PRIVILEGES I see
GRANTEE  TABLE_CATALOG  PRIVILEGE_TYPE  IS_GRANTABLE
'sec_user01'@'localhost'  def  USAGE  NO
But I don't understand why I have no problem connecting using ADODB but the mysqli connection gives me that error.

Comment: login with your root in phpmyadmin and grand privileges from there!

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to your cpanel (www.example.com/cpanel)
2. Go to MySQL add    database wizard
3. similar to "add database", "add_user" you will    have a button
   to add user" to the "database".
4. click on it,
5. added user should list under "priviledged user" for that "database".

---

Answer (score 0):

The grant statement was wrongly formatted

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON `secure_login`.* TO 'sec_user'@'localhost'; is wrong
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON secure_login.* TO 'sec_user'@'localhost'; works.
```

Why did it work the first time I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

i have had this error a few times before, and to my understanding, which is limited on this error is that a many of things could be causing it, first and foremost try to reset your password, the way you do this is by going into a terminal and type.

$ mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass

make notice to fill in your credentials where oldpassword, password, and newpass.

then try my php script i made, it will show you what fields you left blank and will use default parameters for them if they are still blank. the comments that pop up will also disappear within 10 seconds.

file 1

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
<title>MySQL Connection test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    timedHide(document.getElementById('messages'), 10);
}

function timedHide(element, seconds)
{
    if (element) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }, seconds*1000);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="messages">

<?php include "constant.php"; ?>

</span>
</body>
</html>
```

file 2

constant.php

```
<?php
$database_ip = ""; //database ip adress goes inside quotes
$database_port = ""; //database port goes inside quotes
$database_name = ""; //database name goes inside quotes

$database_admin_user = ""; //admin username goes inside quotes
$database_admin_pass = ""; //admin password goes inside quotes

//do not modify anything past this point unless you know php well.

$database_link = null;

$database_defaults = array("127.0.0.","3306","MySQL","root","");
$error_defaults = array("error_no_101" => "required field *IP is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_102" => "required field *PORT is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_103" => "required field *NAME is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_104" => "required field *USER is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_105" => "required field *PASS is empty, using default parameters!");

if(empty($database_ip)){
    $database_ip = $database_defaults[0];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_101"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_port)){
    $database_port = $database_defaults[1];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_102"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_name)){
    $database_name = $database_defaults[2];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_103"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_admin_user)){
    $database_admin_user = $database_defaults[3];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_104"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_admin_pass)){
    $database_admin_pass = $database_defaults[4];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_105"] . "<br/>";
}

$database_link = mysqli_connect($database_ip, $database_admin_user, $database_admin_pass, $database_admin_pass);

if (!$database_link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($database_link) . "\n";

mysqli_close($database_link);

?>
```

i hoped this helped (=

Answer (score 0):

THis error disappear when you add some privileges except the insert select update in user privileges!
So go add add all the privileges in cpanel with username and database name.